How to tell Integrate that a function is periodic
Recently, I was calculating the integral of several periodic functions, then I realized that Integrate doesn't give the expected result.
Let's start with this one
Integrate[Exp[I b Sin[-x + a]] Cos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]

In this case, the integral isn't evaluated, after making the substitution u=-x+a, we have
Integrate[Exp[I b Sin[u]] Cos[a - u], {u, -Pi + a, Pi + a}]

which (again) remains not evaluated. Using a rule for arc's sum, we get
Cos[a] Integrate[Exp[I b Sin[u]] Cos[u], {u, -Pi + a, Pi + a}] + 
 Sin[a] Integrate[Exp[I b Sin[u]] Sin[u], {u, -Pi + a, Pi + a}]

And now, Integrate recognizes that the cos part is zero, but the sin still remains without a result. However, we can see that the function is periodic and the last integral can be written as
Sin[a] Integrate[Exp[I b Sin[u]] Sin[u], {u, -Pi, Pi}]
(*ConditionalExpression[2 I \[Pi] BesselJ[1, b] Sin[a], 
 b \[Element] Reals]*)

which gives the right answer. My question is, is there a way to tell Integrate that the function is periodic since the beginning?

With version 14.1 it works -- although quite slowly
$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Integrate[Exp[I b Sin[-x + a]] Cos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}] // AbsoluteTiming


Assuming[b \[Element] Reals,
  Integrate[Exp[I b Sin[-x + a]] Cos[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]] // AbsoluteTiming



Thanks a lot. I am currently using version 13. I will try 14.1 instead.
